# How to translate theme name

Tags: translation

I want to translate a theme from English to Chinese. I've added `load_theme_textdomain` and successfully translated many of words to the Chinese language, but I don't know how to translate "theme name".

Answer (score 0):

Use Loco translate plugin it is great and change theme name.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Comment: is there a way that I do not use the plugin?

Comment: You can use one method from below:                                                      (1) In po file add "theme name" and save and then run po file here https://po2mo.net/ .After that download mo file that is generated add in your language folder.   (2) http://ronangelo.com/change-or-translate-text-on-a-wordpress-theme/